# My notebook does'nt want to boot from ODD nor USB just from HDD

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb, boot, reinstall

I have a Toshiba Satellite C650 notebook and I have a litlle problem.

I would like to make a full Windows reinstall, but unfortunately the computer doesn't want to boot from ODD. I have tried a lot of CDs -Original Win XP, Ubuntu, Hirens Boot CD, Ultimate boot cd, but none of them want to boot.

The boot order is correct, ODD is the first but it skips instantly and boots from the hdd. I tried to boot from External ODD and from USB Pendrive but it doesn't boot. If i remove the HDD and put a bootable disk into the external odd it boots but if i want to use the internal odd nothing happens it writes `No bootable media. Please insert system disk`

If i replace the old hdd to a new one i could reinstall the system but only from the External USB ODD. I have installed the latest bios (1.6) but still no success.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

my first guess is that the BIOS settings are not correct.
check if there are any more settings, apart from the boot order some BIOSes have a "allow booting from removable media" settings

Comment: Hi! 
I checked all the bios settings but unfortunately there are no other options. It is a insyde h20 bios. Original version was 1.4 and i upgraded it to 1.6. I think it is a hardwer related problem, maybe motherboard failure.  Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Disable UEFI Boot and try again (enable CSM Boot).
If you install Windows you may want to enable UEFI Boot after the installation.